# Controlling the type of data returned by JsonPath's read() method

Tags: java, jsonpath

I want JsonPath to always return the data it parses as a string. However, the return type of JsonPath's `read()` method varies depending on the the type of the data being parsed, because JsonPath always makes a guess at what the data type is and returns results of that type.

The problem is I have no way of knowing what kind of data is going to be returned as I only have access to a set of paths I need to feed into the `read()` function. This means that I have to store the returned JsonPath data in an array of Objects and use a pretty ugly collection of if/else-if statements involving the `instanceof` keyword to figure out what the data is (and then cast it to the appropriate type).

Does anyone know a way to force JsonPath to return a string? Or can another think of a better work around?

Here's what I'm doing right now (in Java):

```
ArrayList<Object> realData = JsonPath.read(dataDumpFile, current.getPath());
```

What I'd like to do:

```
ArrayList<String> realData = JsonPath.read(dataDumpFile, current.getPath());
```

In the [docs](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when) I found this:

> When using JsonPath in java its important to know what type you expect in your result. JsonPath will automatically try to cast the result to the type expected by the invoker.
>
> ```
> //Will throw an java.lang.ClassCastException    
> List<String> list = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.store.book[0].author")
>
> //Works fine
> String author = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.store.book[0].author")
> ```

What does "the type expected by the invoker" mean?

Comment: If you get back a list of strings (presumably JSON strings), would you try to parse them into objects then?

Comment: I'd parse them into strings. I'm outputting to a text file, so strings would be easiest to work with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a typical use case of JsonPath, the library assumes [we know what to expect from a path](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when):

- Is the path *definite*? A path is:

  - definite if there can only be one result, e.g. `$..book[0]` for the first book.
  - indefinite if multiple results are possible, e.g. `$..book[?(@.isbn)]` for all books with certain properties; the return type can be a list.
- What specific type should the result be? For example, you can expect return types `Date` or `List<Date>` instead of `Object` or `List<Object>`.

In your case, all of the above doesn't matter because you don't know the type beforehand, you just need the results as JSON strings.

The default parser in JsonPath is too smart and will convert everything to nice LinkedHashMap objects; but if you use [JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/ff760658dd1facb12eb59dc0aadb1c384c1617ac/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/spi/json/JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider.java), you'll get results as [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) objects, and you're one `toString()` call away from JSON string results.

Even better, you can use the JsonPath [option](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#options) `ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST`, which means you don't need to worry about whether your path is definite or indefinite (whether your result is a single object or a list).

```java
// Example from https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#path-examples
final String json = "{\"store\": {\"book\": [{\"category\": \"reference\",\"author\": \"Nigel Rees\",\"title\": \"Sayings of the Century\",\"price\": 8.95},{\"category\": \"fiction\",\"author\": \"Evelyn Waugh\",\"title\": \"Sword of Honour\",\"price\": 12.99},{\"category\": \"fiction\",\"author\": \"Herman Melville\",\"title\": \"Moby Dick\",\"isbn\": \"0-553-21311-3\",\"price\": 8.99},{\"category\": \"fiction\",\"author\": \"J. R. R. Tolkien\",\"title\": \"The Lord of the Rings\",\"isbn\": \"0-395-19395-8\",\"price\": 22.99}],\"bicycle\": {\"color\": \"red\",\"price\": 19.95}},\"expensive\": 10}";

Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
        .options(Option.ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST, Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();

ArrayNode node = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$.store.book[*]"); // indefinite
for (Object o : node) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
// {"category":"reference","author":"Nigel Rees","title":"Sayings of the Century","price":8.95}
// {"category":"fiction","author":"Evelyn Waugh","title":"Sword of Honour","price":12.99}
// {"category":"fiction","author":"Herman Melville","title":"Moby Dick","isbn":"0-553-21311-3","price":8.99}
// {"category":"fiction","author":"J. R. R. Tolkien","title":"The Lord of the Rings","isbn":"0-395-19395-8","price":22.99}

node = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$.store.book[0].author"); // definite
for (Object o : node) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
// "Nigel Rees"
```

Comment: Great idea to use a different parser. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Can I be sure that any the `toString()` method will always work? I know `Object`implements `toString()`, but the `Object` implementation wouldn't work for me here.

Comment: I think it should be fine. Looks like the `ArrayNode` stores `JsonNode`s, which implement `toString()` (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#toString()), so I guess I'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let assume this is your JSON:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Instead of parsing the whole JSON you can query that and get only those string values (as paths), then you can easily loop through them and get what you want:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder()
     .options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();

List<String> authorPathList = using(conf).parse(json).read("$..author");
```

This will return the list of authors paths:

```
["$['store']['book'][0]['author']",
"$['store']['book'][1]['author']",
"$['store']['book'][2]['author']",
"$['store']['book'][3]['author']"]
```

Now you can loop through them and get your value:

```
for (string authorPath : authorPathList) {
    String author = JsonPath.parse(json).read(authorPath);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know what the type of `author` is. Even if I request a `List<String>` it may give me back something totally different. `author` could be a list for all I know.

Comment: Sine not all objects are convertible to string, I don't recommend forcing that unless I am sure it will be safe (for example string/int/decimal)

Comment: I can ensure safety using the instanceof key work and an if/elseif block like I describe in the question. That's not ideal though, which is why I'm asking for alternatives.

Comment: what I meant was whether you know that all values are of certain types or not (types that are convertible to string)? If yes let me know and I will update my answer to cover how to get always string out of the value...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but have a list of candidates. Right now I'm throwing an exception of I find encounter something outside of the list that I don't have custom logic to handle. I think the best thing to do would be to try a different parser (the Jackson one that has been suggested seems like a good match for what I'm looking to do).